# No Wired section in network settings (20.04)

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

My wired internet connection is not working and I cannot access the wired section of the network settings. I have basically the same question as [Wired option missing in Network Settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185368/wired-option-missing-in-network-settings) and many others, except I tried all the proposed solutions for those cases and they are not working for me.

I am using a Dell XPS-15-9500 without ethernet port. Therefore I have to use a Dell DA200 adapter to connect to a wired connection. This was working perfectly well for a long time. Suddenly it is no longer working and I can't even find the "Wired" connection in settings. (The wireless connection is still working.)

Some possibly useful information:

```
$ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:ce:34:e6:4e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 23784  bytes 2711203 (2.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23784  bytes 2711203 (2.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp0s20f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 129.104.107.227  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 129.104.107.255
        inet6 fe80::5727:c7c6:79ce:d6f3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:41:a9:a9:eb:e2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 214538  bytes 230570417 (230.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 110262  bytes 39170210 (39.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp0s20f3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:41:a9:a9:eb:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: gpd0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500
    link/none
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/ether 02:42:ce:34:e6:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff


$sudo lshw -c net
  *-network                
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 00
       serial: dc:41:a9:a9:eb:e2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-44-generic firmware=63.c04f3485.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.u ip=129.104.107.227 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:604b11c000-604b11ffff
```

---

I also want to find the MAC address because the network connection is administered to work with some kind of white-list so I want to make sure the issue does not lie there (I don't have access to any other wired connection to test this.)

---

The problem seems to be with the Dell DA200 adapter. Using a different adapter I managed to connect to the internet. I am still interested in finding out how to make my old adapter work again if possible. Or to find a definitive test that there is a hardware problem with the adapter. (It also was not detected on a Mac. I'm starting to think there is a hardware problem. It is a bit weird since the USB part of the adapter is still working.)

Comment: Your dock probably needs a firmware update. Check the Dell web site.

Comment: @heynnema, would there be any reason why I suddenly would need a firmware update after it had been working for a long time? Also how would I update it. Googling for it only lead me to a windows based method.

Comment: Software Updater may have updated something that broke it. The power adapter may be bad. Don't Google it. Go directly to the Dell web site for the firmware update, and instructions. Let me know if firmware fixes it, and I'll write a formal answer for you.

Comment: @heynnema, so I went to the Dell website already. Searching on DA200 I encounter the following possibly relevant pages with driver updates: https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=7w38g
and 
https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/product-support/product/dell-universal-dongle-da200/drivers.

Neither offer anything that I could install on ubuntu. They only support Windows.

Comment: So take your dock to a Windows machine and do the update.

Comment: I currently don't have access to one but I will try when I do.

Comment: You can try using FreeDOS. http://www.freedos.org/

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema, Thanks for the reminder. I think it is a hardware issue with the adapter. Tthe USB part is also giving trouble now. So I think I should delete the question.

Comment: Have you updated the dock's firmware yet?